# Spring: autowiring DAO into a utility class not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dao, autowired

I have an annotation driven spring mvc project templated after the JBoss web mvc sample. (Spring, Hibernate, JPA 2.0)

I have a utility package where I want to put reusable classes for obviously utility functions.
Specifically I have a LogonUtilities class where I want to query a database to get information.

I autowire my DAO there but when I debug the DAO is always null and fails with that exception.

I have read and tried many things - I know I've probably come across the solution already - but missed something and moved on and tried something else. I probably am not googling the correct terms since annotations are new to me. (I've worked with spring & hibernate for years - but with xml)

I've added this to my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="util"/>
```

which I thought was all I needed to do.

This is what I currently have in my LogonUtility class - but it doesn't work, keywordDao is always null.  I think I could probably get it to work if I wired the DAO to a LogonUtility bean in the applicationContext (the old way) but I would think there's a better way to do it with annotations.

```
@Service    
public class LogonUtilities {

    @Autowired private KeywordDao keywordDao;
```

My application isn't brand new, I probably have ten working controllers and over a dozen working DAOs at this point, including a Keyword Controller and DAO that already does CRUD operations, so I don't think my setups with that stuff is incorrect.
I just have some code I want to reuse that pulls from a database.

Thanks in advance.

*in my code it's actually called "TrainingKeyword" not "Keyword"
This is the nullPointer error because the DAO is null

```
10:52:07,673 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Training/Home: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at util.LogonUtilities.trainingOffices(LogonUtilities.java:59) [classes:]
    at filter.LogonFilter.doFilter(LogonFilter.java:100) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

This is the code where the error happens

```
//Set TrainingOffices
List<TrainingKeyword> kList1 = keywordDao.getAllTrainingKeywordsByName("Level 200 Training Offices");
```

Comment: Show us where you use the `LogonUtilities` _bean_.

Comment: The sematics of the xml in my applicationContect is not the problem. ("/") before the closing tag.  That was me trying to get the xml to display properly in the question.  The backslash is not in the code.

Comment: What? No, show us where you use the `LogonUtilities` in your code. Show us the stack trace of the NPE.

Comment: One place I use LogonUtilities is in my Logon filter, another is in a controller - which I just found out may not be correctly set up either. I tried to post the controller code but it wouldn't let me.  Basically I was just doing an Autowired LogonUtilities lu;

Comment: When you post code, select all of it and click the `{}` button. Post the stack trace and we can go from there.

Comment: 10:52:07,673 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Training/Home: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at util.LogonUtilities.trainingOffices(LogonUtilities.java:59) [classes:]
 at filter.LogonFilter.doFilter(LogonFilter.java:100) [classes:]

Comment: Please edit (edit button below it) your question and add all those details requested there. It is not readable in comments. Put the full thing.

Comment: Now I understand - it's my first post

Comment: So the error happens in `LogonFilter`. Let's see it. If the `LogonUtitlies` is autowired there, is the `LogonFilter` bean declared in a context where `annotation-config` is enabled?

Comment: @user3541797 But are yuo trying to use the DAO in a Servlet Filter? If so...it's normal you have a nullpointerexception; ServletFilter is outside the spring framework control

Comment: @AngeloImmediata The `Filter` is used through a `DelegatingFilterProxy` which retrieves it from the context. (Assuming it's used correctly.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis well if it's as you say, it should work...can we see the LogonFilter and how it is configured?

Comment: You can fork correct configuration here:
https://github.com/azee/hibernate-example

Comment: Mostly Its something to do with the way LogonUtilities is used. Make sure LogonUtilities is correctly initialized in a spring way. You are using @service. so make sure component scan happens on this package.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by listening to your ideas and with help from this question.
[JPA is not Autowiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853893/jpa-its-not-autowiring)

Basically I had already tried everything that worked - but never all together.  I was constantly making edits to my code trying to get it to work and always had either something missing or something bad. For anyone with a similar question here are the steps

In my LogonFilter I added

```
 @Autowired private LogonUtilities lu
```

In my LogonUtilites class I added

```
@Autowired private TrainingKeywordDao keywordDao;
```

There was no need to add the LogonUtility bean to my applicationContext - I took it out and it still works.

Thank you to all that helped - your ideas kept making me rethink what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a `@Autowired private KeywordDao keywordDao;` but you not getting any autowiring error. but `@Autowired` is by default `@Autowired(required=true)` meaning that these dependencies are by default mandatory, and throw an error if not met.

No autowiring error is received, so the conclusion is that it seems that this class is not being scanned for autowiring at all.

If it would then an error would be thrown. Try to see why the class is not being autowired, here are some common causes:

- the package where the class is placed is not being scanned, is the name of the classes package util or a subpackage?
- The scanning is being done in the wrong spring context. Most Spring applications have two contexts, one root context and one servlet dispatcher context. Try to move the component scan `<context:component-scan base-package="util"/>` from one context to the other, by copying this configuration line from one XML file to the other.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you don't think the util package is being scanned correctly.  As a test I moved the LoginFilter to another package (repo) which is set up exactly the same way (context:component-scan...) as util.  My repo package has all my DaoImplementations and they work fine with @Autowired.  The test failed and the KeywordDao is still null in the LoginFilter class when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `base-package` is the fully qualified path of the service from the root on, and make sure that `KeywordDao` is annotated with `@Repository`.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem as I have two other packages set up that are working fine and my DAO is annotated with @Repository

Comment: And `LogonUtilities` is also instantiated using spring injection, and all parent objects are too, and not using `new` operator anywhere?

Comment: I am not using the new operator to instantiate LogonUtilities.  I'm not sure I understand completely what you mean by spring-injection. I am new to annotations.  In the old way I would have created a service bean for every DAO and then in the servlet I would have created a bean pointed to my controller with references(properties) to any service bean I needed.  In this new world I have no servlet code and use @RequestMapping to map requests to controllers.  I suspect you are on the right path

Comment: I tries adding <bean id="logonUtilities" class="util.LogonUtilities" /> but I still think I need to inject the DAO somehow.  Could you please detail all the steps all the steps?  I suspect I've already done them but never together.

Comment: I can advise you to check out the examples on http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ , they are very simple and show how a basic spring application has to be set up. Also, in case you use Spring 4, get rid of any XML and use annotation based configuration. You also see this in the example: create a configuration class, annotate it with `@Configuration
@ComponentScan`. This way your LogonUtils should be autowired automatically as spring will detect the `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: Also, as you just start with spring, try first creating a sample spring app so you understand the basics, and then start refactoring your code.